# Which driver framework should I use to create Virtual Microphone on Windows Platform?

Tags: kmdf, wdm, wdf, umdf

I want to create `Virtual Microphone` for `Windows platform`.

Which driver framework out of [Windows Driver Frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Frameworks) ([Kernel-Mode Driver Framework (KMDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-Mode_Driver_Framework) and [User-Mode Driver Framework (UMDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Mode_Driver_Framework)) and [Windows Driver Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Model) should I choose to make it work on Windows 10 and above?

Answer (score 0):

By Default, any new driver development should be done in **WDF**, as for today the syntax of KMDF or UMDF (2.0) is the same.

you should be able to switch between KMDF and UMDF (unless you are using some special function only for KMDF or UMDF)

WDM is only used in special cases and I would not recommend writing drivers in it. (In most cases you can port WDM drivers to KMDF, you can always use WDM function in KMDF drivers if you don't find equivalent solution for it)

I recommend you start reviewing the [Microsoft Driver samples][1] repo
[1]: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples